# How can I have String.tokens use more than one delimiter?

Tags: sml

Because String.tokens is a curried function, I know I can change

`String.tokens (fn` ***`c =\> c = #" "`***`) "hello world";`

to a string that would contain all the delimiters, but I am just confused about the actual dictation of how.

One of the forms that I tried was:

```
fun splitter nil = nil
  | splitter str = 
    let
      val c = " ,.;?:!\t\n"
      val s = String.tokens (fn (c:string,x:char) => c=Char.toString c x) str
    in
      s
end;
```

With c being the string of the delimiters, but I know something is very wrong. If anyone could point me into the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.tokens` takes two arguments: a predicate to determine if a character is a token; and a string to split. The first argument is the important part. We don't have to specify a character to split on, just a rule to identify that character.

If you turn a string containing the token characters into a list with `String.explode`, then it's easy to use `List.exists` to find out if a character is in that token string.

```
fun splitOn(str, tokens) =
  let 
    val tokens' = String.explode tokens
    fun isToken c = List.exists (fn c' => c = c') tokens'
  in
    String.tokens isToken str
  end;

splitOn("hello world | wooble. foo? bar!", " |.?!");
(* ["hello", "world", "wooble", "foo", "bar"] *)
```

Comment: I just want to clarify, String.tokens takes isTokens as a function that takes tokens' which is a list of chars? List.exists returns true or false based upon whether or not one of the char's in tokens' is in the str? Then based on that true or false, String.tokens deletes matching chars from tokens'?

Comment: `isToken` does not accept `tokens'` as an argument. Rather `isToken` is a closure that has access to `tokens'` when it is evaluated later. `String.tokens` uses this function to determine if a character is a token, and uses that information to split the input string `str`.